# how to filter field values based on other field id of same model in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

Here i want to filter the all the items of each group

let us consider my model as

```
class ItemsList(models.Model):
   invoice_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class ItemsInvoice(models.Model):
    items = models.ForeignKey(ItemsList)

class StockItems(models.Model):
     item_invoice = models.ForeignKey(ItemsInvoice, blank=True, null=True)
     group_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

For example let us consider my database values as:

```
item_invoice    |    group_id
 
 2206           |   1
 2207           |   1
 2208           |   2
 2209           |   3
 2210           |   4
 2211           |   4
 2212           |   4
 2213           |   5
```

Now how can i write my filter statement based on group_id filter item_invoice and based on this item_invoice id's filter the items and based on these items ids filter invoice_number

Comment: It is still not clear to me what you aim to do.

Comment: Do you want to obtain the `StockItems` with an `item_invoice` that has an `items_id` to a related `IntemsList` invoice number.

Comment: Based on group_id of StockItems i need to first obtain the item_invoice that has an items_id to a related IntemsList invoice number

Comment: So if you query with `group_id = 4`, then you want to retrieve `InvoiceItem`s with ids `2210`, `2211`, and `2212`?

Comment: It is not clear to me what the `invoice_number` is doing here, since there is a direct link between `StockItems` and `ItemInvoice`. This thus means that one can query the relation without taking a look to the `ItemsList`.

Comment: Yes if i query with group_id=4 i need to retrive item_invoice with ids 2210,2211,2212

Answer (score 0):

Yo can filter the `ItemInvoice`s by filtering on the `group_id` of the related `StockItems`:

```
ItemsInvoice.objects.filter(stockitems__group_id=my_group_id).distinct()
```

where *`my_group_id`* is the `group_id` for which we are looking. If there are multiple `StockItems` objects that link to the same `ItemsInvoice` and `group_id`, then we will retrieve only one instance for each `ItemsInvoice` due to the [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) call.